# How to edit page length in datatables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I need help changing the number of entries shown in datatables. Their documentation says your supposed to use pageLength. This is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "language": {
            "pageLength": 200  
        }
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Here is the table. http://thesgn.com/board/index.php?pages/testmemberlist/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the latest version it's `lengthMenu` what you have to change as below:

```
"lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
```

So if you want to display `25` records just remove `10` from the list above in both the dimensions.

Here is the **[Source](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html)**

**EDIT :**

to display all the records use only `"lengthMenu": [[-1], ["All"]]`

**EDIT 2:**

Try this

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "paging": false
} );
```

Comment: then you have to give `"lengthMenu": [[-1], ["All"]]`

Comment: That didn't work either. It even removed all the jquery stuff http://thesgn.com/board/index.php?pages/testmemberlist/

Comment: Then that should work!!! what do you mean by **It even removed all the jquery stuff** Can you show some visual on how it is and how it should be. Some screenshot will do!!

Comment: oh sorry wrong thing. this is how it should not look. http://i.imgur.com/yJo0G5V.png this is how it should look http://i.imgur.com/9Glgauj.png

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)